# Gadget Mode in Rpi Compute Module?

Tags: raspbian, compute-module

Does anybody know how to put the Rpi Compute Module in Gadget Mode or a way to pass files from this module to the PC via USB? I have found this but for the Rpi Zero.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=143203) on the Raspberry forum. Looks like gadget mode on the compute module requires a [patched dwc2 driver](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/pull/1343).

Comment: Hello there, thank you for answering me. I am kind of new with the Raspberry so can you tell me how to install the patch?